# bad_alloc thrown on brute force task

Tags: c++, c++11, bad-alloc

My program below throws bad_alloc, on a brute force task. I believe that it is being caused by something within my functions, but I cannot find out what is causing it. Could somebody please help me find what is causing this error? The problem statement is below, and then my code is below that.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**
Write a program that reads two numbers (expressed in base 10):
N (1 <= N <= 15)
S (0 < S < 10000)
and then finds and prints (in base 10) the first N numbers strictly greater than S that are palindromic when written in two or more number bases (2 <= base <= 10).
Solutions to this problem do not require manipulating integers larger than the standard 32 bits.

**CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string convert(int num, int base)
{
    int quo = 100000;
    int rem = 0;
    string to_reverse;
    while (quo > 0)
    {
        quo = num / base;
        rem = num % base;
        to_reverse += to_string(rem);
        num /= base;
    }
    reverse(to_reverse.begin(), to_reverse.end());
    return to_reverse;
}

bool is_pal(string conv_num)
{
    string reversed_conv_num = conv_num;
    reverse(reversed_conv_num.begin(), reversed_conv_num.end());
    if (reversed_conv_num == conv_num)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout("dualpal.out");
    ifstream fin("dualpal.in");
    int n, start;
    cin >> n >> start;
    vector<int> finals;
    int times = 0;
    for (int i = start + 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
        if (times == n)
        {
            for (auto x : finals)
            {
                cout << x << "\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                if(is_pal(convert(i, j)) == true)
                {
                    times++;
                    finals.push_back(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174834/discussion-on-question-by-andy-n-bad-alloc-thrown-on-brute-force-task).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the following line:

```
while (quo >= 0)
```

What is the result of `x/y`, if `x < y`? Especially, what is the result of `0/x`? Guess, the result is always 0, so the `==` part in your condition will always be true, resulting in an endless loop adding `'0'` again and again until no more memory is left... So just check for  `> 0` instead.

Side note: You don't need the `quo` variable anyway:

```
while(num)
{
    int rem = num % base;

    // OK, this won't do the trick; you try to append an integer,
    // but need a character instead!
    //to_reverse += rem;

    // if base always is smaller than or equal to 10 anyway,
    // you can just do:
    to_reverse += char('0' + rem);

    // if you want to support arbitrary bases even greater, you can do instead:
    to_reverse += "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[rem];
    // (or capital letters, if you prefer)

    num /= base;
}
// and now don't reverse here - you are just interested in if the
// string is palindrome, not in correct number representation...
```

By the way: Checking for being palindrome can be done more efficiently (avoiding the copy):

```
if(!s.empty())
{
    auto l = s.begin();
    auto r = std::prev(s.end());
    while(l < r)
    {
        if(*l != *r)
        {
            return false;
        }
        ++l;
        --r;
    }
}
return true;
```

*Edit in response to question:*

> I changed it to quo > 0 instead of quo >= 0, do you know why my program is outputting an enormous list of integers?

```
for (int j = n + 1; j <= 10000; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int k = 2; k <= 10; k++)
```

You have created an enormous number of iterations: (10000 - n) * n * 9 and you'll likely get quite a number of palindromes from...

You might rather want something like this:

```
while(n && start < 10000)
{
    for(int base = 2; base <= 10; ++base)
    {
        if(palindrome(start, base))
        {
            --n;
        }
    }
    ++start;
}
```

OK, above is not precise, you can get some values more than required from the inner loop, leaving it to you to fix...

Comment: I edited this to quo > 0 and it does not have any effect

Comment: I changed it to quo > 0 instead of quo >= 0, do you know why my program is outputting an enourmous list of integers?

Comment: @AndyN. Have you had a look at your loops? `for (int j = n + 1; j <= 10000; j++) for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) for (int k = 2; k <= 10; k++)` - how many iterations do you expect, especially if n is small, lets say 7...

Comment: I updated my code, it still does not work... it outputs empty file

Comment: @AndyN. Sure it does - you never write anything to the file, only to console... change all occurences of `cout`/`std::cout` to `fout`, which is the file you opened; if you want to have output on both file *and* console, you need to write twice, both to `std::cout` *and* `fout`...

Comment: Side note: you are editing away the original problems in the question (cause of `bad_alloc` thrown, then bad conversion, then too much loop output). This way you make all the answers given so far obsolete, and in your case, the problem doesn't even match the title... In general, it is better to ask new questions with updated code, possibly marking it as follow up of the original question by providing a link to. At least, you should leave the old code and make the edits clearly visible (similar as I did). However, if multiple people answer, whom do you reward for then?

Comment: @AndyN. Look at your posted code. Where do you actually write *anything* to `fout` ???